# Target Span Class inside item label :checked

Tags: css

I'm trying to target a span class located inside a label. Is this possible with css? I can affect the label, but I would really like to change the background color of item_title:

```
<style>
.item input[type=checkbox]:not(old):checked + label + item_title,
.item input[type=radio]:not(old):checked + label + item_title,
.item input[type=checkbox]:not(old):checked + span + label + item_title,
.item input[type=radio]:not(old):checked + span + label + item_title {
  background: #007cd1;
}
</st

<div class="item">
    <input data-price="45.00" data-label="Starter TV" id="tv_starter" type="radio" name="tv_choice" value="Starter TV" class="required">
    <label style="height:250px;" for="tv_starter"><span class="item_title">Starter TV</span><br />Our Starter TV Package, $45.00</label>
</div>
```

Comment: ```.item_title { background-color: green; }```

Comment: @flappix This doesn't answer the question because it sets the `background-color` for the `.item_title` class to always be green. The need is to only change the background when `input:checked`.

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely possible. But you have to correct some errors in your code.

First, I'm not sure what `not(old)` refers to. Is `old` a classname?

Second, regarding classnames. Be sure to refer to them in your css with the `class` identifier `.`, so `.item_title` is the right way to refer to that class.

Third, there are different types of `combinators` within css. `+` is the adjacent sibling combinator. `>` is the child combinator.

In your html, `label` is the adjacent sibling of your input, and `.item_title` is the child of `label`.

Finally, you are trying to use the `[type=checkbox]` type selector when you should be using `[type=radio]` to match your html.

See below and give this a good read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

```css
.item input[type=radio]:checked + label > .item_title {
  background: #007cd1;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <input data-price="45.00" data-label="Starter TV" id="tv_starter" type="radio" name="tv_choice" value="Starter TV" class="required">
    <label style="height:250px;" for="tv_starter"><span class="item_title">Starter TV</span><br />Our Starter TV Package, $45.00</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `css` is invalid. Use this one to make an `input[type='radio']` blue if he is selected:

```css
.item > input[type='radio']:checked ~ label > .item_title {
  background: #007cd1;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <input data-price="45.00" data-label="Starter TV" id="tv_starter" type="radio" name="tv_choice" value="Starter TV" class="required">
  <label style="height:250px;" for="tv_starter">
    <span class="item_title">Starter TV</span>
    <br />Our Starter TV Package, $45.00
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the span is a **child** of the `label` not a *sibling* you need

```
.item input[type=checkbox]:not(old):checked + label > item_title /* etc*/
{
  background: #007cd1;
}
```